# Launching an application from Window service in C#

Tags: c#, windows-services, uac

I am trying to launch an application from a Windows service running on LocalSystem account. I am able to launch the application but it asks for UAC to run.

Is it possible to launch an application from a Windows service without prompting the UAC?

Comment: Probably not as UAC is designed to prevent things like this happening without the user knowing.

Comment: Run the service as admin or turn off UAC, I would say

Comment: but i can not turn off the UAC,beacuse if user run this EXE externally by double clicking , it should ask UAC

Answer (score 0):

UAC is specifically designed to prevent such behaviour. How would it know which exe is good and which is malicious?

Things you can try:

- Run Windows service with admin privileges
- Allow it to interact with desktop
- Turn off UAC

But I would rather forget about that unless you trying to expand a botnet...

This is how you can run it as admin

- Run `services.msc`
- Select the service right click, go to Properties
- Type user name and password (if you change the password, you have to manually update it for the service)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answere ,please Can you tell me how to run service as Admin..?

Comment: Just use an account that has administrative privileges to run your service.

Comment: Thanks Guys for your Respons..but i found the Solution to bypass the UAC from the windows service ,i have done it by using registry ,and changing the value in registry..